# Unable to setup amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp in Windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, cmake, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I  am a newcomer and I am struggling to setup amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp in my Windows laptop. I am running this command:

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -DBUILD_GSTREAMER_PLUGIN=ON -DBUILD_JNI=TRUE
```

but getting an error:

```
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:603 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:825 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:199 (pkg_check_modules)
```

Though, I have installed both the gstreamer-1.0-msvc-x86_64-1.20.2 and gstreamer-1.0-devel-msvc-x86_64-1.20.2 and added the env variable `GSTREAMER_1_0_ROOT_MSVC_X86_64`.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/issues/715#issuecomment-924426526

This one worked for me.
If you use the recent gstreamer for mvsc, edit your CMakefile.txt and change "C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64" to "C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64" .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you, the issues is with incorrect path